# hibernate retrive data from 2 tables

Tags: hibernate

Is it possible in hibernate without adding one to many mapping on entity and without having foreign key relationship in DB ,to return list of parent containing child ?

I have two tables A and B.

table 'A' has columns idA,name,city,first_id columns

table 'B' has columns idB,col1,col2,second_id columns

**I have not done any explicit foreign key relationship betwen tables.
Also I have not mapped any one-to-many mapping between entities.**

But from **both tables first_id and second_id column represents relationship between them**.

I wanted to return data as, ***one A can have multiple B data.***

Here what I am doing,

```
public List<A> Data(){  // This should return A list containing respective B list

Criteria critA = session.createCriteria(A.class); // load table A data
List aList = critA.list();
for(int i=0;i<aList.size();i++)// iterate over table A list
{ 
A a = (A) alist.get(i);
String **firstId**= a.getFirst_Id();

Criteria critB = session.createCriteria(B.class); // load table B data
critB.add(Restrictions.eq("second_Id", **firstId**)); // query Table b data with respect to table A "first_id" column
criB.list();
}

}
```

I am not understanding how I can add criB.list to aList and return only finally aList ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query unrelated entities using HQL/JPQL as follows:

```
SELECT a, b FROM A a, B b WHERE b.second_id = a.id
```

Since you're doing a fake `one-to-many` relationship, there is no need for entity `A` to maintain any information about the relationship.  The relationship can easily be driven straight from entity `B`.  If this relation was being modeled using `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` without a join-table, this would precisely be how the database schema would be modeled too.

In order to handle the result set from the above query:

```
List<Object[]> results = entityManager.createQuery( query ).getResultList();
for ( Object[] row : results ) {
  A a = row[ 0 ];
  B b = row[ 1 ];
  /* note that A will repeat for each matched B relationship */
}
```

In order to obtain the desired result you're after, you would want to do use the above fragment as follows:

```
public List<A> getData() {
  Map<Integer, A> aMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
  List<Object[]> results = getEntityManager.createQuery( query ).getResultList();
  for( Object[] row : results ) {
    final A a = row[ 0 ];
    final B b = row[ 1 ];
    if ( !aMap.containsKey( a.getId() ) ) {
      aMap.put( a.getId(), a );
    }
    // get the transient property List<B> bList;
    aMap.get( a.getId() ).getBList().add( b );
  }
  return aMap.values();
}
```

As I point out, you'll need to place a `@Transient private List<B> bList` property on the entity `A` so that you can populate it after you iterate the result set to return a `List<A>` that each contain a `List<B>` instances.

**Followup**
If you apply the relationship in the entity mappings, you can then simply query your entities as follows:

```
public List<A> getData() {
  final String query = "SELECT a FROM A a JOIN FETCH bList";
  return getEntityManager().createQuery( query ).getResultList();
}
```

You are basically telling hibernate to `JOIN` both entities and fetch the list so that it is eagerly loaded and available when your `getData()` method returns.

Comment: thanks a ton for the detailed answer. I have one doubt. instead above solution , if I apply one-to-many relations in entity and in DB  will there be chances of  "A will repeat for each matched B relationship" as you mentioned above ?

Comment: See followup in post.

Comment: Naros , Also if I want to add 1 more many relation of 'C' with 'A' alongwith 'B' , i.e. one A can have many B , many C .I hope this will work. 1) final String query = "SELECT a FROM A a JOIN FETCH bList, JOIN FETCH cList"; (if I think of one-to-many mappings) 2)aMap.get( a.getId() ).getBList().add( b ); aMap.get( a.getId() ).getCList().add( c );(If I think of HQL/JPQL and adding transient relation for C in entity)